# Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry Without Redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery-forms-plugin

Is there a way to upload a video to youtube and get the returned results from `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry`? My problem seems to be that when I upload to Youtube it redirects back to another page. I need my JavaScript form to process the redirect when its done.

I use the following to create my Action URL and Token:

```
    $yt = $this->_auth_youtube();

    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('User Submission');
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('-');
    $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Entertainment');
    $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('user, upload');
    $tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry);

    $this->data['token'] = $tokenArray['token'];
    $this->data['formAction'] = $tokenArray['url'] . '?nexturl='.   site_url('art_of_tomorrow/video_submit_result');
```

I then run the form through the ajaxForm plugin so I can have a Progress Bar:

```
$('#upload-youtube').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#progress-container").show();
        $("#upload-youtube").fadeOut();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
    },
    success: function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
        console.log('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + xhr + $form);
    },
    target: $("#nutsack")
});
```

I cannot simply do a success handler (`window.location.href = 'the_url'`) because when you upload to YouTube, it redirects back to your next_url with parameters.

Does anyone know of a solution?